# Is it possible to create new table in Alfresco Database?

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

I have started to use Alfresco CMS.
In my project, there is a new table to create in an existing Alfresco Database.

I would like to know whether I can create new tables in an Alfresco database or not?
And If it *can* create, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, this is a bad idea. If you need a custom table, put it in your own schema, not in Alfresco's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Alfresco ->How to Creat Custom Table and accessing it](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=6522) 
Hope this may helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Already exists a component for Alfresco Share which allow this feature with "zero code", in easy and flexible way. Is available in Alfresco Addons http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-metadbconnector-component. Developed and maintained by VenziaIT (**http://venzia.es**). We hope this help to the community.

Greetings!